# hudson cannot fetch from git repository

Tags: git, tomcat, hudson, tomcat6

I have a Hudson server, and a git repository, both running on our server (an ubuntu machine).
Whenever I try to build my app with hudson, he says the follwing

```
Iniciado pelo usuário anonymous
Checkout:workspace / /usr/share/tomcat6/.hudson/jobs/ECF/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@176150c
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:workspace / /usr/share/tomcat6/.hudson/jobs/ECF/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@176150c
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@192.168.0.10/git/germantech.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from servidor / servidor - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR:  (Underlying report) : Error performing command: git fetch -t ssh://git@192.168.0.10/git/germantech.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Command "git fetch -t ssh://git@192.168.0.10/git/germantech.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
```

what am i missing here?
Ideas? thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Ok, made it work!
first, i've logged with my hudson user (`sudo su - -s /bin/bash tomcat6`) and then, i've deleted my .ssh folder.
after this, i just followed [this](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) link, and made a ssh login without password
now, hudson can do a fetch without have to especify a password

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create an ssh relationship between hudson and git server.

You only need to do this once.

Steps:

1. Log in in the hudson machine with the hudson user.
2. create a ssh private and public key:

   `ssh-keygen -t dsa` 
   Leave an empty passphase.
   Now you have 2 files in the hudson home under the .ssh folder: id_dsa and id_dsa.pub.
3. Copy the key to your repo using:

   `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub hudson@gitserver.machine.com`
4. Log out and verify you can now ssh without having to provide a password.

Hudson should now be able to connect.

Comment: i've logged into 'tomcat6' (sudo su - -s /bin/bash tomcat6) user, which is the user that runs hudson. the error now is the following: https://gist.github.com/1633627. i still can't login via ssh. after 'sudo su - -s /bin/bash tomcat6', i tried 'ssh 127.0.0.1', but still ssh is asking me password, and doesn't let me log in. what am i missing here?

Comment: hudson runs under the hudson user

Comment: @GermanAttanasioRuiz why do i have to keep passphrase empty? Can it not work with a passphrase?

Comment: You will have to write the passphrase every time you connect

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the `.ssh` folder inside `tomcat6` home folder (hudson runs with tomcat6 user here, because I use hudsons's war) and then, used [this](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) tutorial and it finally worked